# Programmatically selecting items in a WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview

How can I set the selected items in a WPF ListView programmatically?

Basically, I have a `List<SomeEntity>` and a ListView that is bound to another `List<SomeEntity>`. I need to mark the items that exist on the first list as selected.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
var lv = yourListView;
lv.SelectedItems.Clear();
foreach(var item in selection)
     lv.SelectedItems.Add(item);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx

Comment: It should have been obvious now that I look at it. The documentation was misleading, as it says the property **gets** a list of selected items, without mentioning it can also be used to **set** them. Thanks!